# Creating array of objects; Best way to do it?

Tags: java

Good afternoon.

I am attempting to make a small game inspired by Among Us. The game will feature two bandits if there are 7 or more players, and one bandit if the player count is 6 or less.

I have run into a problem though, so I am attempting to create multiple constructors, here is how I imagine the layout to be.

Console -> Input names separated by comma -> String[] names -> newPlayer Constructor

The newPlayer constructor will then determine the number of players, and sort them into their respective constructor, using Math.random to determine the bandits.

Bandit route
newPlayer Constructor -> Bandit Constructor -> Player Constructor

Cowboy route
newPlayer Constructor -> Bandit Constructor -> Player Constructor

The problem is that after the data is given to the Player constructor, I'd like to create an array of type Player[], so I can easily access the data within, without creating invidual Player variables, and then making this array accessible to the rest of the classes within the package. I'm looking for the most concise way to do it.

Although I feel like this may not require code for context, I'll provide it in case it helps answer my question.

Bandit Class

```
    package Sorting;

public class Bandit {
    private int playerID;
    private String playerName;
public Bandit(int ID, String name) {
    this.playerName = name;
    this.playerID = ID;
    Player newBandit = new Player(playerID,true,playerName);
}
}
```

Cowboy Class

```
package Sorting;

public class Cowboy {

    private int playerID;
    private String playerName;
    
    public Cowboy(int ID, String name) {
        this.playerID = ID;
        this.playerName = name;
        Player newCowboy = new Player(this.playerID,false,this.playerName);
    }
    
}
```

newPlayer Class

```
package Sorting;

public class NewPlayer {
    private String name;
    private int playerID;
    private int impostor1, impostor2;
    
    NewPlayer (int ID, String name, int playerCount) {
        if(playerCount<=6) {int impostor1 = (int)Math.random()*playerCount;
        if(impostor1==this.playerID) {
        Bandit bandit1 = new Bandit (this.playerID, this.name);}
        }
        else {
            impostor1 = (int)Math.random()*playerCount;
            impostor2 = (int)Math.random()*playerCount;
            while (impostor1 == impostor2) {
                impostor2 = (int)Math.random()*playerCount;
            }
            if(impostor1==this.playerID) {
            Bandit bandit1 = new Bandit (this.playerID, this.name);}
            if(impostor2==this.playerID) {
            Bandit bandit2 = new Bandit (this.playerID, this.name);}
        }
        for(int i=0;i<playerCount;i++) {
            if ((this.playerID!=impostor1)&&(this.playerID!=impostor2)) {
                Cowboy newCowboy = new Cowboy(this.playerID,this.name);
            }
        }
        }
        
    }
```

Player Class

```
package Sorting;
public class Player {
    
    public int playerCount;
    private int playerID;
    private boolean playerBandit;
    private String playerName;
    
    public Player(int id, boolean bandit, String name) {
        this.playerID = id;
        this.playerBandit = bandit;
        this.playerName = name;
        playerCount++;
    }
    public String getPlayerName() {return this.playerName;}
    public boolean getBandit() {return this.playerBandit;}
    public int getPlayerID() {return this.playerID;}
}
```

I do not think the Tester class would be required to answer this question, but I'll provide it. Be aware, this part is not finished.

```
package Sorting;
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {
    private static int playerCount;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter player names, separated by a comma: ");
        String nameList[] = input.nextLine().split(",");
        playerCount = nameList.length;
        Assigner.Assignment(nameList);
    }
    public int getPlayerCount() {return playerCount;}
}
```

I'd like the array of Players to be created within the tester class, and accessible to the rest of the classes within the package.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have read your question, and seems like you try to ask one, specific question, but that comes somewhere in the middle of the text. Please, instead of telling entire story of what game you're creating, try to narrow down your question to the specific problem you're experiencing.

Comment: *The problem is that after the data is given to the Player constructor, I'd like to create an array of type Player[],* - so, you want to create an array of players with one Player instance? why constructing one Player should create an array?; *so I can easily access the data within, without creating invidual Player variables, and then making this array accessible to the rest of the classes within the package. I'm looking for the most concise way to do it.* - I'm not sure I understand what do you mean here..

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I’m looking to create an array of type Player. So in a scenario where they are 8 players, if I wanted to get the name of player 6 I can playerData[6].getPlayerName(); I’m more or less asking for the proper way to declare an array of an object type, and then fill the array with the Players I just created. I’m sorry if I do not make sense, I’m trying my hardest. I’m a new Computer Science student, I am trying my best :(

Comment: *I’m looking to create an array of type Player.* - where? in the Player constructor? how/why shall you put the players in one array member of one Player object? why not to just define some List/Array of the players outside somewhere and store your players there?; *I’m more or less asking for the proper way to declare an array of an object type, and then fill the array with the Players* - `Object[] array = new Object[int_size];` will define an array of objects, however, **do not store** Player instances there.. you will have hard time to fetch the `Object` references. Rather, go for `Player[]`.

Comment: Being new students is not a problem at all. My suggestion will be to **clarify** and understand clearly what you want to do (at the modelling/design level), and then come up with a specific question.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I will remember that for next time. I was looking to create the array in the Tester class. I think I have the answer to what I was looking for in the answers section. Thank you.

Comment: If you define `Object[] array = new Object[size];`, then anything you'll fetch from it will be of type `Object`, and you will need to explicitly cast it down to your type. Rather, prefer creating `Player[] players = new Player[size];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"I'd like the array of Players to be created within the tester class"**: I would suggest using List interface instead of native java array (much easier to use). Something like this: `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>()` and you can use `players.add( /*player*/ )` and `players.get(/*idx*/)` to add and retrieve.

**"accessible to the rest of the classes within the package"**: a default class property is accessible for classes within the same package. Like this: `List<Player> players;` or already initialized: `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();`. Don't use any modifier like `private`, `public` or `protected` and it will mean this property is "default" access (within same package). See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html